# run a single ERT test programmatically

Tags: ert

I'm trying to write a piece of code that runs a single ERT test programmatically. In the ERT manual, they show an example that creates a test body and then runs the body, like so:

```lisp
(ert-deftest ert-test-record-backtrace ()
   (let ((test (make-ert-test :body (lambda () (ert-fail "foo")))))
    (let ((result (ert-run-test test)))
```

But... `(ert-run-test` won't work with a normal `ert-deftest` name such as the one shown above, `ert-test-record-backtrace`. If I try doing that I see an error

```lisp
(ert-run-test 'ert-test-record-backtrace)
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument arrayp my-deftest)
```

The code `(ert-run-tests-interactively)` runs the usual ERT function that prompts for tests in the minibuffer.

How can I run one or more ERT tests programmatically? Is it even possible? I'm working on this kind of syntax right now, but it is not working. I think I need to extract the function body value of `my-deftest`, but I don't know how to do that yet.

```lisp
(ert-run-test (make-ert-test :body my-deftest))
```

Update: I tried to put my whole test function inside the `make-ert-test` format shown in the example above, and was able to run the test. Not pretty code, because of the indenting. And the result was in square brackets, which I don't understand yet. But I can see the `value: t` in there that I would like to extract. So I'm getting closer.

```lisp
(setq result
  (ert-run-test
   (make-ert-test :body
                  (lambda ()
                    ;; my ert test code here
                    (should (equal tcoll output))
                    ))))

[cl-struct-ert-test-passed "" (((should ...) :form (equal ... ...) :value t :explanation nil))]
```

After more experimentation to dig the answer out of the `result` returned (it was an array), here is the code that gets me to the `t` that I could see.

```lisp
(setq data (aref result 2))
(((should (equal tcoll output)) :form (equal ...)) :value t :explanation nil))
(nth 4 (car data))
t
```

It works, but it seems like a brute force approach because I have to copy my `ert-deftest` code into a separate `lambda` function as shown above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use the example from the ERT manual:

```el
(ert-deftest ert-test-record-backtrace ()
  (let ((test (make-ert-test :body (lambda () (ert-pass "foo")))))
    (let ((result (ert-run-test test)))
      (should (ert-test-failed-p result)))))
```

The test should pass obviously. A list of symbols naming an ert-test object will be returned with

```el
(apropos-internal "" #'ert-test-boundp) ;⇒ (ert-test-record-backtrace)
```

And finally show the number of available tests that passed as expected:

```el
(ert--stats-passed-expected (ert-run-tests 't (lambda (&rest args)))) ;⇒ 1
```

The listener in `ert-run-tests` may be an arbitrary function called for side-effects.

Comment: Thank you for your help. With `apropos-internal` I can see my deftest names, but they are not test objects, since `ert-run-test` rejects them with `wrong type argument` errors. I will go an experiment with listeners now, since I've never used them either.

Comment: `(ert-test-passed-p (ert-run-test (ert-get-test 'ert-test-record-backtrace)))` is what you're looking for.

Comment: The `(ert--stats-passed-expected (ert-run-tests 'my-deftest ..listener))` syntax was closest to answering my question, I think. I can work with it. But I find it quite odd that in order to do something "so simple" as running a single test programmatically, I must call one of the "don't call functions with double hyphens in the name" functions. Thank you again.

Comment: Sorry, our comments were out of sync. You are exactly right, `(ert-test-passed-p ...)` was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you again. I wonder why I couldn't find any of this in the manuals or online doc...  Did I miss something obvious, or did you find out this info by working with the source code or something?

Comment: You're welcome. IIRC the [ert-modeline](https://github.com/chrisbarrett/ert-modeline) package got me inspired to look into ERT. In addition, source code is always enlightening.

Answer (score 5):

You can try `ert-run-tests-batch`, e.g.

```
(ert-run-tests-batch 'ert-test-record-backtrace)
```

but the results are not returned as a value, but rather via messages in `*Messages*` (or on stdout).  Otherwise, you can use `ert-run-tests` which is a bit more complex to use because you need to provide a listener function:

```
(ert-run-tests 'ert-test-record-backtrace
               (lambda (event &rest args)
                 (message "Test event %S: %S" event args)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your test event example. Wow, what a huge amount of output from the little listener that dumps the event and args (and my little deftest function was tiny!).